# Asserting the existence of tags of methods

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

Is it possible to assert that the summary tag exists here?

```
/// <summary> this is my summary </summary>
public void myMethod()
{
    // dostuff
}
```

My documentation for my methods relies on tags like summary/category/param, and I would like to ensure that every method has the specified tags?

Comment: You could do it with a Rosyln code analyser.

Comment: You could also run a post-build step to verify the generated XML against a XSD schema.

Comment: @Steve cool can you point me to a resource?

Comment: asserts are runtime concepts, not compile time

Comment: @DanielA.White how about asserts in Nunit?

Comment: nunit are runtime as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code analyzers were created just for this situation.  Instead of using unit tests to validate that the code has the correct comments, you can generate errors during the build.

For this particular case, there are existing StyleCop Analyzers that can do this for you.  [SA1600 ElementsMustBeDocumented](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1600.md) and [SA1604 ElementDocumentationMustHaveSummary](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1604.md) sound like exactly what you want.

So if you add the [StyleCop analyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers) to your solution/project and then set SA1600 and SA1604 to be an error, then you prevent the code from building until documentation is provided.

If for some reason that doesn't fit your needs, you can always create your own analyzer to cover your use case.

Comment: how do i specify which elements must be documented?

Comment: You don't. The rules I supplied will cover the fact that documentation exists and that a summary tag exists. If you need further rules, you could look at other rules in the `SA16XX` range or create your own analyzer if those rules don't fit your needs.

Comment: i would like it to have both summary and category tags

Comment: I don't see an analyzer for category tags, so you would have to write that one yourself.

Comment: NOOOOOO !!!!!!!!!  would it be just exactly the same as the summary one, and then i can just change every instance of the "summary" string to be "category" ?

Comment: does a stylecop analyzer include the automatic fix for the found styling issue?

Comment: The repository is linked in my answer, so it should be easy to check if they have a code fix for SA1604. From a quick look, it doesn't appear that they have a fix for that.